# How can I call OCaml functions from a Python program?

Tags: python, ocaml

I've got a large legacy program that is written in OCaml, and I'd like to be able to call some OCaml functions from my Python program.

How can I do this the easiest way?

Comment: [This page](http://proj.badc.rl.ac.uk/cedaservices/browser/ipython/IPython/frontend/html/notebook/static/codemirror/mode/ocaml/index.html) seems to suggest that there's a way to connect the [IPython notebook](http://ipython.org/) with OCaml.

But since I've never done any work with interfacing python and OCaml, I can't be sure that's what you want

Comment: This link doesn't work for me: I get error 403 "Forbidden"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Directly, no. However, if you create a `C` API for your Ocaml library, you can call that API via. Python's `ctypes` module or similar. Likewise, if you expose a network service for your OCaml application, Python can call into that.

Answer (score 8):

You might find useful Pycaml, a Python-OCaml interface allowing to call OCaml functions from Python and vice versa.

Be sure to look for the 2011 or later version, which is based on a 2002 version.

---

Edit: removed link, since 10 years after my answer the hosting moved from http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/hump.en.cgi?contrib=792  to sourceforge. In 10 years, new options might have emerged, for instance a quick search returns **pyml**.

Comment: This link is now broken.

Comment: 10 years later, the link has changed. The library is not maintained anymore. Another library, which was born 5 years after the above answer, seems to be a better choice now. I hope this answer helped people during the last 10 years (at least it got a few upvotes), but now I don't think it's worth maintaining the answer anymore. I'm upvoting the new answer (posted 5 years later) that points at the new library.

Answer (score 6):

Pycaml is no more maintained: nowadays there is pyml and lymp
to do that.

pyml: http://pyml.gforge.inria.fr
lymp: https://github.com/dbousque/lymp

Both of them are available in opam (opam install pyml lymp).
I have not tried them yet, but since I know the author of pyml is very competent, I would bet on that one.