# Shared libraries in Poly/ML

Tags: sml, ml, polyml

Is it possible to build a shared library using Poly/ML?
I want to be able to create a `C` API for a Poly/ML library, and invoke/load it from different programming languages (e.g., Python). Did anybody try to do that? 
I know this can be done in OCaml:

- [How can I call OCaml functions from a Python program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795785/how-can-i-call-ocaml-functions-from-a-python-program)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer provided by David Matthews, Poly/ML main developer (http://www.polyml.org/):

> The simple answer is no, at least at the moment.  I had a look at this
>   and wondered if it was possible.  The foreign-function interface
>   allows for call-back functions so there is the mechanism to produce a
>   C function that when called calls an ML function.  The difficulty I
>   could see was that in order to produce a shared library the closure
>   for the C function has to be "unpicked" so that relocation information
>   can be produced for addresses within the closure.  I'd have to add
>   something to libffi to do that.  It doesn't look to be too hard for
>   X86 but I haven't taken it any further.  There may be other issues
>   that I'm not aware of.